# Jquery operator issue

Tags: jquery

I think I've made some mistake with the operator, but I can't seem to figure it out, please help.

```
 $("#registersubmit").click(function(){
    if($("#registerinput_username").val() == "" || $("#registerinput_email").val() == "")
    {
    alert("All fields are required!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Its just missing $ ,you should use selector either jQuery or $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `$` in second selector of condition of `if` statement. `("#registerinput_email").val()` should be `$("#registerinput_email").val()`

```
if($("#registerinput_username").val() == "" || $("#registerinput_email").val() == "")
{
     alert("All fields are required!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `$` for your second selector, it should be

```
$("#registerinput_email")`
```

instead of:

```
("#registerinput_email")
```

so your code should look like:

```
if($("#registerinput_username").val() == "" || $("#registerinput_email").val() == "")
// ------------                                ^ add $ here
{
    alert("All fields are required!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#registersubmit").click(function(){
    if($("#registerinput_username").val() == "" || $("#registerinput_email").val() == "")
    {
    alert("All fields are required!");
    }
});
```